# Conditional inside for loop not passing. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, conditional-statements

I can't figure out what's wrong, please help.

new Num is passed in, console logs show that it is finding the correct element for activeSlide

```
var activeSlide = $("#ep"+newNum);

for (var i=0; i< allSlides.length; i++){

    var slidegrab = $("#ep"+i);

    console.log(slidegrab == activeSlide)
    if (slidegrab == activeSlide){
        console.log("stop loop and stop shuffle");
        return;
    } else {
        slidegrab.appendTo('#slideshow');
    }
}
```

My console will display the correct names for both the slidegrab and activeSlide variables.  The conditional will display false for each loop, never is true.  What am I missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: They're probably two distinct jQuery wrappers.  You'll probably have to compare them by ID?

Comment: why don't you compare `newNum` and `i` instead?

Comment: your console.log should be giving you `true` or `false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're two different jQuery object. You need to compare the DOM elements.

```
slidegrab[0] === activeSlide[0]
```

Or maybe you want to keep track of the current slide by index and no by element. That's more common.

Comment: Thanks, these are the little things that get me...I'm an actionscripter writing javascript.  I'll look into using the index instead, probably better for optimization anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You could compare ids instead of wrappers:

```
var activeSlide = $("#ep"+newNum);

for (var i=0; i< allSlides.length; i++){

    var slidegrab = $("#ep"+i);

    if (newNum== i){
        console.log("stop loop and stop shuffle");
        return;
    } else {
        slidegrab.appendTo('#slideshow');
    }
}
```

Comment: would be very confusing according to the variable's name!